# Is there a way to quickly compute the signature of a string for help detecting string changes?

Tags: java, string, signature

We have a non-critical tag whose value is a string. We want to check the changes of the tag value. But we don't want to do string comparison as this involves client-server and instead we want to calculate some sort of value for the string and use the value to help detect the string changes. As the string is non-critical, we wonder if there is a very simple and quick solution to calculate such value for helping on detecting changes to the string.

Comment: string.hashcode()? (with a low risk of hashcode collision)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use the .hashCode()**

`String.hashCode()` isn't perfect because it is lossy.  So it's possible the string could change and it would have the same hashcode.  (but this won't happen often)  Almost every time the string changes, its hash code will change also.

So you know what you're getting into, the code for `String.hashCode()` is this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    int h = hash;  // the cached hash value
    int len = count;  // the number of characters in the string
    if (h == 0 && len > 0) {
        int off = offset;
        char val[] = value;

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            h = 31*h + val[off++];
        }
        hash = h;
    }
    return h;
}
```

Comment: It will happen often enough.  `int` is only 32 bits wide.

Comment: Yes.  http://preshing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/probability-distribution.png

Comment: That's not the same as the chances that you will miss a change in the string based on hash code.  The OP isn't looking for collisions in a big set.

Comment: That is a very fair point.  However 1 / 2^32 is only a fair formula if you ever use this software only once - that's what the 1 stands for.  I would expect a very big benefit of the 32 bit value if you propose intentionally compromising on an apparent requirement; and I did not notice any.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  But do not use a hash code if you need uniqueness.  Use SHA256 digests.

```
String tag = "...";
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
byte[] digest = md.digest();
```

Comment: I guess I don't understand why string comparisons would be unwanted, but byte array comparisons would be fine?

Comment: Size I guess...  I'd welcome a question clarification on this as well.